# Probability of symmetric random 1D walk finishing in a square point

Tags: probability, random-walk

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, such that $P(X_1 = -1) = P(X_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Suppose $S_n = \Sigma_{k = 1}^n X_k$. How can I find $P_n := P(\exists m \in \mathbb{N}_0 \text{ such that } S_n = m^2)$?

I have an assumption, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n = 0$, but don't know, how to prove it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: What do you mean by "finish in a point"? What is the process that is being "finished"?

Comment: That after $n$ steps the $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i$ is equal to $k^2$, where $\xi_i$ are independent random variables such that $P(\xi_i=-1)=P(\xi_i=1)=1/2$

Comment: @ Olga Zhukova  I have found numerically a surprisingly weak decay $P_{n} \simeq \frac{1}{\log(n)}$ for $n \to \infty$. From the density of squares would have rather conjectured a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ decay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see, that $$P(S_n = k) = \begin{cases} \frac{C_n^k C_{n - k}^{\frac{n - k}{2}}}{2^n} & \quad \text{, if } n - k \text{ is even } \\ 0 & \quad \text{, if } n - k \text{ is odd }\end{cases}$$

From the aforementioned formula we can conclude, that

$$P_n = \begin{cases} \Sigma_{k = 0}^{\lceil \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \rceil} \frac{C_n^{4k^2} C_{n - 4k^2}^{\frac{n - 4k^2}{2}}}{2^n} & \quad \text{, if } n \text{ is even } \\ \Sigma_{k = 0}^{\lceil \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \rceil} \frac{C_n^{4k^2 - 4k + 1} C_{n - 4k^2 + 4k - 1}^{\frac{n - 4k^2 + 4k - 1}{2}}}{2^n} & \quad \text{, if } n \text{ is odd }\end{cases}$$

Now, if you want to show, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n = 0$, you can do this via [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)